# Refresh canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

Helle every body, i explain my problem, in my android project, i draw a bitmap in a canvas. It works but this bitmap is not display while i not touch my canvas with a finger. I search how to solve it . Thanks a lot for your help.

This is my code :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBm, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    if(ModificationActivity.isMask == 1){
        Log.e("ondraw", "ok cest un masque");
        canvas.drawBitmap(masqueTab[0], 0, 0, paint);

    }
}
```

This is my complete class :

```
This is my complete class

public class DrawingTouchView extends View {

private ArrayList<Draws> drawsList = new ArrayList<Draws>();
private static Bitmap[] masqueTab = new Bitmap[1];

public static Paint paint = new Paint();
public static Path path = new Path();

public Button btnReset;
public LayoutParams params;
private Bitmap  bm, scaledBm, mBitmap;
private String      imagePath;
private int         eraser       = 0;
private static int  paintOn      = 0;
private int         resizeOn     = 0;
private static int  textOn       = 0;
private static int  maskOn       = 0;
private int         newX;
private Point       origine;
private int         minimalWidth = 70;
private Images      correspondanceImage = null;
private Texts       correspondanceTexte = null;
private static Context mContext;
private static EditText result;
private static int textId = 0;

public DrawingTouchView(Context context, String _imagePath) {
    super(context);

    mContext = context;
    result = new EditText(mContext);

    imagePath = _imagePath;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(15f);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

    BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bfOptions.inDither              = false;
    bfOptions.inPurgeable           = true;
    bfOptions.inInputShareable      = true;
    bfOptions.inTempStorage         = new byte[32 * 512];
    mBitmap                         = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    if (bm == null) {
        File file = new File(imagePath);
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        try {
            if (fs != null){
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
            }
            int nh = (int) (bm.getHeight() * (512.0 / bm.getWidth()));
            scaledBm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 512, nh, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fs != null) {
                try {
                    fs.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBm, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    if(ModificationActivity.isMask == 1){
        Log.e("ondraw", "ok cest un masque");
        canvas.drawBitmap(masqueTab[0], 0, 0, paint);

    }else if(resizeOn == 1){
        int newWidth = newX - origine.x;
        if(newWidth < minimalWidth){
            canvas.drawBitmap(correspondanceImage.scaleImage(minimalWidth), origine.x, origine.y, paint);
        }else{
            canvas.drawBitmap(correspondanceImage.scaleImage(newWidth), origine.x, origine.y, paint);
        }
    }else if (textOn == 1){
        Texts t = ModificationActivity.textsList.get(0);
        TextView finalText = t.getTextView();
        ModificationActivity.photo.addView(finalText);
        finalText.setOnLongClickListener(new MyTouchListener(1));
        finalText.setTag("noCopy");
        finalText.setId(t.getId());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.e("touch vent", "ok");
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();
    int i = 0;

    //mode dessin
    if(eraser == 0 && paintOn == 0){
        Draws dessin = new Draws(i, Color.GREEN);
        drawsList.add(dessin);
        paint.setColor(dessin.getColor());
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
                handleTouch(pointX, pointY);
                return true;
            case ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
                break;
            case ACTION_UP:
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        postInvalidate();
        i++;
    //mode effaceur
    }else if((eraser == 1) && (paintOn == 0)){
        Draws effaceur = new Draws(i, Color.YELLOW);
        drawsList.add(effaceur);
        paint.setColor(effaceur.getColor());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
                handleTouch(pointX, pointY);
                return true;
            case ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
                break;
            case ACTION_UP:
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        postInvalidate();
    //mode redimenssion d'objet
    }else {
        if (paintOn == 1) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case ACTION_MOVE:
                    newX = (int) event.getX();
                    if (resizeOn == 1) {
                        correspondanceImage.setBottomRight(new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
                        correspondanceImage.setTopRight(new Point((int) event.getX(), correspondanceImage.getTopRight().y));
                        correspondanceImage.setBottomLeft(new Point((int) correspondanceImage.getBottomLeft().x, (int) event.getY()));
                        correspondanceImage.setCenter(new Point((int) (correspondanceImage.getTopRight().x + event.getX()) / 2, (int) (correspondanceImage.getTopRight().y + event.getY()) / 2));
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_UP:
                    for (Images anObjectsList : ModificationActivity.objectsList) {
                        final ImageView image = anObjectsList.getImage();
                        final RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) anObjectsList.getContainer();
                        int childcount = container.getChildCount();

                        //On affiche l'image sur la photo
                        container.addView(image);
                        image.setTag("noCopy");
                        image.setId(correspondanceImage.getId());

                        //On definit l'image dragable
                        image.setOnLongClickListener(new MyTouchListener(0));

                        //On cherche l'image dropé pour la supprimer
                        mainloop:
                        for (int k = 0; k < childcount; k++) {
                            View v = container.getChildAt(k);

                            if ((v.getId()) == (correspondanceImage.getId())) {

                                Log.e("je l'ai!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "ok" + v.getId() + ", corresp =" + correspondanceImage.getId());
                                ImageView im = (ImageView) container.getChildAt(k);
                                correspondanceImage.removeImage();

                            }
                        }
                        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
                        lpt.setMargins(anObjectsList.getOrigine().x, anObjectsList.getOrigine().y, 0, 0);
                    }
                    paintOn = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean handleTouch(float pointX, float pointY) {
    Point newPoint = new Point();
    newPoint.x = (int) pointX;
    newPoint.y = (int) pointY;

    mainloop:
    for (int i = 0; i < ModificationActivity.objectsList.size(); i++) {

        correspondanceImage     = ModificationActivity.objectsList.get(i);
        double distTopRight     = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getTopRight().x - newPoint.x, 2)  + Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getTopRight().y - newPoint.y, 2));
        double distTopLeft      = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getTopLeft().x - newPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getTopLeft().y - newPoint.y, 2));
        double distBottomRight  = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getBottomRight().x - newPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getBottomRight().y - newPoint.y, 2));
        double distBottomLeft   = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getBottomLeft().x - newPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getBottomLeft().y - newPoint.y, 2));
        double distCentre       = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getCenter().x - newPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(correspondanceImage.getCenter().y - newPoint.y, 2));

        if(distTopRight <100){
            Log.e("en haut a gauche", "on supprime");
        }

        if (distTopLeft < 100 || distBottomRight < 100 || distBottomLeft < 100 || distCentre < 100) {
            Log.e("correspondanceImage","" + correspondanceImage.getId());
            origine         = correspondanceImage.getOrigine();
            paintOn         = 1;
            resizeOn        = 1;

            break mainloop;
        }
    }

    if(correspondanceImage == null && !(ModificationActivity.textsList.size() == 0)){

        breakloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < ModificationActivity.textsList.size(); i++) {

            correspondanceTexte          = ModificationActivity.textsList.get(i);
            double distTopRight     = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getTopRight().x - newPoint.x, 2)    + Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getTopRight().y - newPoint.y, 2));
            double distTopLeft      = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getOrigine().x - newPoint.x, 2)     + Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getOrigine().y - newPoint.y, 2));
            double distBottomRight  = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getBottomRight().x - newPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getBottomRight().y - newPoint.y, 2));
            double distBottomLeft   = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getBottomLeft().x - newPoint.x, 2)  + Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getBottomLeft().y - newPoint.y, 2));
            double distCentre       = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getCenter().x - newPoint.x, 2)      + Math.pow(correspondanceTexte.getCenter().y - newPoint.y, 2));

            if(distTopRight <100){
                Log.e("en haut a gauche", "on supprime");
            }

            if (distTopLeft < 100 || distBottomRight < 100 || distBottomLeft < 100 || distCentre < 100) {
                Log.e("correspondance texte","" + correspondanceTexte.getId());
                origine         = correspondanceTexte.getOrigine();
                paintOn         = 1;
                resizeOn        = 0;

                break breakloop;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void newText(){
    textOn = 1;
    paintOn = 1;

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialogedit, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    //set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            result.setText(userInput.getText());

                            ModificationActivity.addTextToList(new Texts(mContext, textId, Color.BLUE, (result.getText().toString()), 50, new Point(150, 150)));
                            textId++;
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    //Creation de la boite de dialogue
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    //Affichage de la boite de dialogue
    alertDialog.show();
}

public static void newMask(Drawable drawable){
    Log.e("j'y suis", "ok "+drawable.toString());
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    masqueTab[0] = bitmap;
}
```

}

This is where iMask is manipulated :

```
public void setMasqueVisibility(boolean visible) {
    isMask = 1;
    groupBars.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    drawBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    objectsBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    masksBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void setDrawVisibility(boolean visible) {
    isMask = 0;
    groupBars.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    masksBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    objectsBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    drawBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void setObjectVisibility(boolean visible) {
    isMask = 0;
    groupBars.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    drawBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    masksBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    objectsBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void setTextVisibility(boolean visible) {
    isMask = 0;
    groupBars.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    drawBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    masksBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    objectsBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We will need more code to solve this. Please post most of your code.

Do you clear your path when you lift your finger?
How do you calculate your scaledBm? Or is it just a background image?
Whats your masqueTab?
Whats the idea behind your activity.isMask?
etc

Comment: thanks for your help, so scaledBM is just a background image and it works fine. masqueTab is the array where is stock the bitmap to display in the canvas and isMask is just an int to activate or desactivate the bitmap creation. I post all my class in a new answer

Comment: What I can see from that code is that the masque is newer set, do you do it from another class?
isMask is never set either. It doesnt seem like there is a problem with your path. So I would recommend that you comment out some parts in the onDraw and start error-searching from there.
See my mainanswer

Comment: thanks you but if the first if is commented, i can't put any mask in my canvas

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood. I thought that it was a problem with the path.
You only draw the mask when isMask == 1, that means that your mask is not showing when isMask != 1. Please post the code where you manipulate isMask.

Comment: Im not sure what your app is supposed to do, but Im guessing that you draw something with touch. I think you should check out this tutorial on how to draw custom objects in Android, its a good policy to use a second thread to draw instead of calling postInvalidate() as you do.
original(but maybe down?) http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html

copy: http://www.eis4u.com/2012/02/13/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i/
http://www.eis4u.com/2012/02/13/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii/

Comment: And also the new code you posted doesnt really make any sense. Why do you send in the argument (boolean visible) when you dont use it in your method.